# Replace comma chars within importdata function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm importing a .csv file with the `IMPORTDATA` function. The separator is `;` and decimal char `,` on which Google Sheets automatically applies a text to column. I guess this is the expected behavior from `IMPORTDATA` but as a result, my file is not correctly parsed.

I've tried to use the substitute function on `,` with `.` but I guess that the text to the column is applied within the `IMPORTDATA` function.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTDATA("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1hosZrfgrKnJJgXkgmPZSKdFoYV_AxKJS"), ",", "."), ";"))
```

Is there any way to import a CSV with `;` as a separator and `,` as a decimal symbol using a single formula?

I've seen solutions using multiple sheets but I'd like to keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks for the editing. I've edited the formula to include an example file.

Comment: I think I found an undocumented feature of importdata for specifying data separator, but I didn't find (yet) one for decimal separator: **importdata(URL, ";")** will correctly import a file which uses ";" as a separator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1hosZrfgrKnJJgXkgmPZSKdFoYV_AxKJS")), ,
 999^99))), " ", "."), ";"))
```

[image: 0]

---

to compensate for space separated values:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(
 IMPORTDATA("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1hosZrfgrKnJJgXkgmPZSKdFoYV_AxKJS"),
 " ", "♠")), , 999^99))), " ", "."), ";"), "♠", " "))
```

Comment: Thanks for the first solution and the edit to account for spaces separated values ! Could you please explain the logic of using transpose ?

My only problem now, is that if I use the second formula all values are detected as text which is a problem later on with Data Studio. It's too bad you can't specify the separator with `IMPORTDATA`.

Comment: double transpose is there for query which is there for concatenating stuff that is wrongly divided into columns (coz you can manipulate CSV input only after it's imported). there are various ways how to re-convert text values back to whatever you need. like `QUERY` with `format` command or `VALUE` (to convert text to numbers) `TO_DATE` etc...